# Cannot reference projects with same name as folder they are in

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Structure looks like this:

```
Solution:"TestS"
         Folder:"Test1"
                Project:"Test1"
                Project:"Test1.Unit"
                Project:"Test1.Integration"
```

It's not possible to reference anything from "Test1" Project inside Test1 Folder. I get the "Add reference to Test1"-prompt but the generated using statements are red: "Type or Namespace name could not be found"

Comment: I have tried your structure and it works, clear you bin folders and rebuild solution

Comment: alright I will try that. Thank you!